# Помогите решить проблему с PHP массивом

Tags: php, массивы, условия

Вот код:

```
$arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB", "123456789990"]; 


usort($arr,function($a, $b){
    return strlen($b)||strlen($a);
});
$arr2 = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
echo join(", ",$arr2);
```

Если в методе `array_slice($arr, 0, 2);`указать значения 2 выведет `123456789990, MongoDB`  а если мы укажем `array_slice($arr, 0, 5);` то выведет `123456789990, MongoDB, Fish, Apple, Ceylon` все 5 значения массива, мне нужно чтоб выводилось только самые длинные значения массива, или на оборот саммые короткие, помогите решить проблему, я новичок в PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...мне нужно чтоб выводилось только самые длинные значения массива, или на оборот саммые короткие...

Та не понятно, какое слово считается длинным, а какое коротким, 'test' - это длинное или короткое, крч дам примерчики, выберете сами:

**Например есть массив:**

> $array = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB", "Seven77"];

---

**1) Сортировка по количеству символов:**

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a);
});
var_dump($array);
```

**Результат:**

```
array(5) {
  [0] => string(7) "MongoDB"
  [1] => string(7) "Seven77"
  [2] => string(6) "Ceylon"
  [3] => string(5) "Apple"
  [4] => string(4) "Fish"
}
```

---

**2) Только те значение, длина которых больше или равно** `$length = 5`**:**

```
$result = [];
$length = 5;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($length <= mb_strlen($value)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

**Результат:**

```
array(4) {
  [0] => string(6) "Ceylon"
  [1] => string(5) "Apple"
  [2] => string(7) "MongoDB"
  [3] => string(7) "Seven77"
}
```

---

**3) Найти максимальную длину, и выбрать элементы с этой длиной:**

```
$result = [];
$length = 0;
array_map(function($v) use (&$length) {
    if ($length < mb_strlen($v)) {
        $length = mb_strlen($v);
    }
}, $array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($length == mb_strlen($value)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

**Результат:**

```
array(2) {
  [0] => string(7) "MongoDB"
  [1] => string(7) "Seven77"
}
```

---

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ ЗДЕСЬ Я ПОНИМАЮ БОЛЬШЕ

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($arr,function($a, $b){
    return (strlen($a)==strlen($b)? 0 : (strlen($a)<strlen($b)? 1: -1));
});
```

После выводите нужное кол-во элементов с начала массива =) самые длинные в начале, короткие в конце.

Comment: Мне нужно что она вообще убрала короткие, или на оборот.

Comment: @МечтаюсоздатьVisualRuby Что значит короткие? это длинной 1 символ? или 10? или 1000?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ну `короткие`, что не понятно-то :D

Comment: $arr = [ "Fi", "Apple", "1"]; короткие  $arr = ["Ceylon12", "MongoDB", "123456789990"]; длинные

Comment: @МечтаюсоздатьVisualRuby как вы определили что `Apple` короткий, а `MongoDB` - длинный? был-же какой-то критерий. почему нам его не сказать?

Comment: Если б знать критерий - то ОP сам бы все сделал.